# Typescript treats boolean like true | false when strictNullCheck is off

Tags: typescript, boolean

I am having the following typescript code:

```
type PossiblePromise<T> = T extends Promise<infer U>
  ? T | U
  : T | Promise<T>;
type Z = PossiblePromise<boolean>;

const a = "a"
const f: () => Z = () => Promise.resolve(!!a);
```

With `strictNullChecks` set to false.

The resulting type `Z` is `boolean | Promise<false> | Promise<true>`, but I would expect it to be `boolean | Promise<boolean>`. So last line produces an error:

```
Type 'Promise<boolean>' is not assignable to type 'boolean | Promise<false> | Promise<true>'.
  Type 'Promise<boolean>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<false>'.
    Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'false'.(2322)
input.ts(7, 10): The expected type comes from the return type of this signature.
```

Any ideas why typescript behaves like this treating `boolean` as `true | false` which should not be the case with strictNullChecks off.

How is it possible to achieve `PossiblePromise<T>` type that works with boolean correctly?

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?strictNullChecks=false&ssl=6&ssc=1&pln=7&pc=47#code/C4TwDgpgBACg9gZwQSwEYBsIwE5wLbIIQA8AKgHxQC8UpUEAHsBAHYAmCsuBRxyLAMwjYoAVXIBYAFBQoAflpQAPmOmyAXIpU58hEhQDc00JCgAtarEQoMWbnuKo4cTAEMW5I1OkBjOCwRgKFdLACJXUN9-QKgBTQAKAEpqSgsaJJSuXSIAOmwIBBcANwh4gEIy10SDIA

Comment: As far as I know, `boolean` is implemented as a union equivalent to `true | false` in TypeScript regardless of whether `--strictNullChecks` is on or off; is there some specific reason you think otherwise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix it by lifting the Promise type. The issue is that `boolean` is a union type, and conditional types are automatically [distributed over union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types). Consider following code:

```
type PossiblePromise<T, Y = Promise<T>> = T extends Promise<infer U>
  ? T | U
  : T | Y;
type Z = PossiblePromise<boolean>;

const a = "a"
const f: () => Z = () => Promise.resolve(!!a);
```

As you can see `Y` is lifted outside condition type, and is used only when needed.

BTW - using `Boolean` is not a fix of your type definition, it is only different type which works well with your implementation (Boolean is not a union type) - consider more about [Boolean](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#general-types). It also means that if you would use any other union type it would have the same wrong effect, check below the difference

```
type T = "a" | "b";
// previous result type would be:
type PreviousResult = "a" | "b" | Promise<"a"> | Promise<"b">
// after the change it will be:
type Result = "a" | "b" | Promise<"a" | "b">
```

Answer (score -1):

```
type Z = PossiblePromise<Boolean>;
```

Comment: can you explain?

Comment: I'm new with Angular but it is expecting you to define a class type here, where Boolean is the class type. Need another to better explain this.

Comment: Best way I can think of it is your telling it to expect a Boolean type value whereas if you specify boolean it would be a value and not a type of value.